# How to disable HATEOAS in production?

Tags: spring-data-rest

My REST API is consumed only by our own mobile apps and it also has some restricted endpoints to be used by an admin UI. It is easy to get the point of entry by observing communication of the mobile app. From there it is very easy for a malicious user to discover all possible endpoints using HATEOAS.

Even if the API is properly protected by Spring Security, there are known security leaks like https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1144 which allow modification to read-only data.

During development, HATEOAS is useful, but I want to disable it in production to make discovery of endpoints more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution implies that you intend to rely on [Security through Obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) to protect your admin functions. This is a bad idea, because a malicious actor could still *guess* the relevant functions that they shouldn't have access to, or simply remember what they learned by traversing your link hierarchy when you last exposed it.

You should definitely implement a robust authentication and authorization mechanism to protect your resources, and then even if a bad actor can discover the routes to those protected resources through the links structure of an unprotected resource, they won't be able to access them. Links are *meant* to be discovered and even if they are discovered by someone they aren't intended for, security best practices should still ensure they do no harm.

Comment: There is a strict mechanism in place for admin access. But it worths nothing if regular users can modify their data using JSON patch (see the bug I have linked). I would need to review the entire SDR JIRA and disable all operations that are buggy.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what problem this causes. If it's *their data*, why shouldn't they be able to modify it?

Comment: Alternatively, isn't the solution "don't use the buggy library", or possibly "block patch requests"?

Comment: Because they can modify fields they are not supposed to, like their access rights, for example if they can figure out the JSON path to it.

Comment: OK, I think I understand the problem better now. Nevertheless, I think you'd be hiding the problem, not solving it. Users are resourceful and I think you have to assume they **will** guess these privileged URLs even without you helping them. Since you are in control of the only code that should access that route, can you block PUT requests at the infrastructure level and write your code not to require PUT?

Comment: Yes I can block specific types either at the security level or by redefining SDR methods and returning HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED. I'm just pissed by the fact that I have to.

Comment: If there are fields of an entity that users are not supposed to modify, that sounds like a business rule rather than security. I would implement it in an EventHandler with `beforeSave` event.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than disabling HATEOAS (your app should be using it as a lookup for endpoints!) you should trust your security layer to do the best job it can.

Here are some considerations:

- Add user authorisation to your admin endpoints. Perhaps you can achieve this with your existing API key infrastructure.
- Move the admin endpoints to a separate, protected API

Neither of these suggestions are quick fixes but I can't recommend disabling HATEOAS. Once it is gone, you *will* find an issue where you need it.

Comment: Yeah, I have the feeling I shot myself in the foot with SDR. Your second suggestion, for example, is prevented by another bug which prevents creating two Spring Data repositories for the same table.

User authorization is there, but cannot help with security leaks inside SDR.